# iPhone dev - Write/read an array of objects to a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization

I've got the array called listOfContactsToLay - it contains Contact objects with 3 string fields. How can I write this array to file successfully?
Here what I've got:

```
-(NSString*)fPath
{
    return [DocumentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quickdial.xml"];
}

//SERIALIZATION
- (void) save:(NSMutableArray*)array
{

   [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:[self fPath]]; 

    NSLog(@"List of contacts been written in file");

}

// get that array back
- (NSMutableArray*)load
{
    NSLog(@"List of contacts is being read from file");
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self fPath]];

}
```

And of course the following doesn't work:

```
-(IBAction)doneWithContacts {
    [ContactManager createXmlInMydocumentsDirectory];
[self save:listOfContactsToLay];
    NSLog(@"List of contacts to lay saved!");
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

it throws invalid argument exception.

What should I do? how do I serialize the MSMutableArray of my objects?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whether your `Contact` class conforms to `NSCoding` protocol.

[More info](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about the format of the file? If not, why not use the built-in methods of the NSArray class?

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath;
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag;
```

See the [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Comment: If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.